# How to change a user reference field from select list to autocomplete in a Views exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views, users

In [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) filter I have added user reference field and its showing me as select drop-down. I have exposed that field in the filter.

Those user reference fields are related to a content type, but I want those as auto-complete fields instead of drop-down, just as taxonomy fields can be drop-down or auto-complete fields.

The issue with select list is that there are thousands of users in that list and it is taking time to load all values and render the page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

To get **User Reference** Field as autocomplete exposed filter,

- Let me consider you have created a user reference field in your content type as `Users-ref`

**Now in your View :**

- Add a relationship for your entity reference field for **Eg:** `Entity Reference: Users-ref` and make it required.
- Now add a filter criteria `User:Name`  with the relationship `Entity Reference: Users-ref`
- you should find `(User entity referenced from field_users_ref) User: Name (exposed)` in your filter criteria now.
- And this should be an autocomplete widget!!

**There is also a module named [Views Autocomplete Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) along with this wonderful [tutorial](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-views-autocomplete-filter)!!**

Comment: views autocomplete filters only works with text field not user reference fields or any entity reference fields

Comment: In the tutorial I mentioned, You could find a way to make it use for entity reference fields. and for user reference I followed the above-mentioned steps without using the module.

Comment: @PravinAjaaz: Views Autocomplete Filters seems to be working for textfields alone. I have user reference fields in that content type, which i am exposing in the view. That one I want to make it as auto-complete instead of drop-down.

Comment: I just followed these steps I listed without installing the module. Did you tried those steps?